# backbone js: Create a new page and redirect to a that page on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am using backbone js to implement a drag and drop report designer. Now my application can drag and drop report components (title, sub title, table, etc.). I referred [this](https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder) to implement my application. Once the design has been done I can get the related script (on a button click) as below.

```
saveReportHandler: function(){     
    console.log($("#target").html());   
}
```

This prints relevant html script for the report design. I want to create a new html page with this script and need to redirect to that newly created page. Since I am a newbie to backbone js, I would be much appreciated any help from you.

My full javascript code looks like below.

```
var SaveReportView= Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "textarea",
el: $('#build'), // el attaches to existing element
events: {
    'click #saveReport': 'saveReportHandler'
},

initialize: function(){
    this.render();
},
//render() now introduces a button to save the report

render: function(){
    $(this.el).append("<button id='saveReport' class='btn btn-info'>Save</button>");

},

saveReportHandler: function(){    
    console.log("#####################"); 
    console.log($("#target").html());   

},

});

var reportView= new SaveReportView();
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to make the real redirect or just use the frontend router to do the trick?

Comment: I want to make the real redirect

Comment: If you want to make the real redirect, I think it's not so related to backbone. You just need to send your data to the backend and use backend to redirect to the target page.